# Help get rid of light spots!

Tags: photo-editing

I need help removing the spots in this picture. How do I do that. I only have an older version of Photoshop elements.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's nothing you can really do to remove the one over the guys face. Half of his face is obliterated. There's nothing recoverable. Sorry. Maybe if you have another good photo of his face, you could perhaps copy and paste it on the image.

Comment: Other possibilities might include painting it back, or cloning using the other half of the face. A highly skilled edit though if you want to make it look even half decent.

Comment: But manualy redrawn face can be even better than the original; remember Whistler's Mother by Mr. Bean.

Comment: @user287001 - LOL. Yeah I remember that. There's also another example when an elderly lady tried to restore [a painting of Jesus](https://imgur.com/6s6PmDK)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure of the capabilities you have with Elements. But if there is no other image of the gentleman that you can paste in a face image, some cloning labor can work. But don't demand perfection. Here I've copied the opposite side of his face, carefully cloned in some parts of his shirt, beard, and background. His smile is just a clone trick by copying over what part of his mouth is available. Again, not perfect and possibly not accurate. But give it some careful cloning and patience.

[image]

Comment: You did a pretty decent job on a particularly difficult task.

Comment: Thanks. It was an adventure...but an honorable one. :)

Answer (score -1):

It depends really on the background behind the lens flare spots.
The three dots in your picture likely will need 3 different methods.

For simple backgrounds like the shirt the "Spot healing tool" will work great.

The spot on the shoes is probably best done with the "Stamp tool". Though a colour correction layer with a mask could work too.

The head will be the most difficult one. The easiest option should be to replace it with a different face.

[image]

Comment: not to belabor the obvious, but perhaps there's another photo of the male that can be transplanted.

Comment: Yes that was the idea. Just that I would not have one of those photos of corse. And if I would have had one, I would not have bothered to do this. As where would be the fun in that?